# DevExpress component Button for asp.net MVC - Change the ButtonClick event using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I'm trying to change the original button click event as in the code below, but the alert('hello') message fires when the view is displayed and not when the button is clicked:

```
<div>

    <!-- THIS IS A SHARED VIEW -->
    @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
  {
    .....
    settings.Name = "btnSaveDetails";
    settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
    settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "DoSomething()";
 }).GetHtml()
  <!-- END SHARED VIEW -->

</div>
<script>
    btnSaveDetails.ButtonClick = alert('hello');
</script>
```

Comment: $(function(){ $('#btnSaveDetails').on('click', function() { alert('hello'); }); );

Comment: @Steve  Perfect! I didn't know we can use devexpress buttons in this way also. If you can post this as an answer I can close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you know the button name is btnSaveDetails but the following simple jQuery on document ready function should work.

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#btnSaveDetails').on('click', function(){ 
       alert('hello'); 
    }); 
 );
```

Comment: I updated the question with the button name, which is inside a shared view and replaced the code with yours, slight modified to              $('#btnSaveDetails').unbind('click');
$("#btnSaveDetails").on('click', function () { alert('kkk'); });</script>
It works but it still fires the original event though.

Comment: You can try :  $("#btnSaveDetails").off('click').on('click', function () { alert('kkk'); }); The unbind() function is now deprecated.